# How to hack a font so the "light" version appears as "regular" to applications?

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape as a vector based drawing program, and unfortunately it is not importing my fonts correctly. The reason is that inkscape will not load variants of a font if they are not styled within the font as "regular", "bold", "italic" or "bold-italic." Now, the font I need to use has a "light" style, so it will not import into Inkscape correctly.

So, I'm trying to hack the font so that to Inkscape, it appears as a totally different font. I basically need to change the Metadata and rename the font or something.

Does anyone know how I can hack a "light" font so that it appears as "regular" to applications? Any ideas on how I can get this working?